# editing cronjob

Tags: pi-4

I have a question about editing a cronjob.
Using a bash script named "fijnstofmeter".

I can edit the cronjob in nano using the crontab -e command.

Checking on my active cronjobs I use the command: "grep -i fijnstofmeter /var/log/syslog".
It returns 2 types of actions:

```
-Mar 17 16:12:01 raspberrypi4 CRON[27764]: (pi) CMD (./fijnstofmeter.sh)
-Mar 17 16:13:01 raspberrypi4 CRON[27783]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash -c "/fijnstofmeter.sh")
```

My question(s):
Is my cronjob running twice?
Where / how can i stop and delete **the first** one.

Thanks for a reply.

Comment: Welcome to RPi SE. Please read ["How to ask a good question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Wrt this question: it's difficult to say since you don't explain the *"bash script named "fijnstofmeter"."*, Why and how is `root` involved in this script?

Comment: Thank you Dirk, The problem is not in the bash file. That is working just fine. My question is about the 2 cronjobs. It looks like there are 2 cronjobs running doing exactIy the same. I can edit the second (root) one in nano with the crontab -e command. How can i delete the first (pi) one?

Answer (score 1):

Each user has his own crontab.
Login as pi, then run `crontab -l`
to check if there are any entries there.

You can remove the cuurent user's crontab completely with `crontab -r`.

Alternatively, if you are logged in as root (oh, horror), you can access the crontab of any user with `crontab -u USERNAME -otheroptions`

More info: `man crontab`.